# D3.js tree diagram producing horizontally asymmetrical nodes/paths

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, d3.js

Most of the nodes in my treeview have binary decision paths. The 'no' or lower path extending from each node is not displaying in symmetry with the upper node (they aren't branching out evenly). I have no idea why. This is a snippet of the issue:
[image]
Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzcyw9zt/4/), this will better explain the symmetry problem I'm having. I want the paths to extend evenly as in [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083). I think it's something to do with this code:

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .source(function (d) {
            return {
                "x": d.source.x + d.source.height / 2,
                "y": d.source.y + 170
            };
        })
        .target(function (d) {
            return {
                "x": d.target.x + d.target.height / 2,
                "y": d.target.y
            };
        })
        .projection(function (d) {
            return [d.y, d.x];
        });
```

but this seems to only sort out the symmetry of the paths, not the nodes themselves.

Comment: The tree layout doesn't really consider this, but you may be able to get what you want by adjusting the [separation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#separation).

Comment: I'll look into it. Just noticed that when I delete .source and .target functions, the paths become symmetrical, but the nodes do not.